# How to remove specific line breaks in PDF

Tags: php, pdf, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have PDF file with unquoted currencies and this file is a little broken. I am using PHP and Smalot\PdfParser\Parser. When I parse the file and get the full text, one line is displayed incorrectly due to line breaks

The code :

```
        $parser = new Parser();
        $pdf = $parser->parseFile($path . '/' . $filename);
        $pdf_text = $pdf->getText();
        $pdf_with_line_breaks = nl2br($pdf_text);
```

The result :

```
PEN    Peruvian Sol    4,145256     0,241240     <br />
GEL    Georgian Lari    2,879715     0,347257     <br />
XAF    <br />
Central African CFA Franc <br />
BEAC    655,957000     0,001524     <br />
FJD    Fijian Dollar    2,341310     0,427111     <br />
BYN    Belarusian Ruble    2,706597     0,369468     <br />
```

My problem is that the PDF creator has not followed the correct principles of PDF compilation and one entry about the currency is mutilated and it would be necessary to format this entry correctly on one line so that it can then be processed with

```
explode("\n", $pdf_text);
```

See attachment

[image]

How is it possible to combine the erroneous lines marked in the attachment to be on one line without line breaks.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74217668/php-pdf-parser-read-content-showing-as-a-two-lines-need-to-fix-it

Comment: I doubt it's possible to deal with issues like this during PDF parsing. The PDF parser simply reads the text from the source file as it is. It might be better to try to deal with issues like this during processing. For example: 1. Get the line from input. 2. split it by tab (or 4 spaces or whatever is used to separate columns). 3. Check the number of columns. If there is not enough columns add next line and try again.